# Concatenating part of a string

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, string-concatenation

I have this function in col A to concatenate some cells to generate an ID:

```
={"ID"; arrayformula(IF(C2:C="";;(LEFT(C2:C;1))&"-"&(LEFT(D2:D;1))&(LEFT(E2:E;1))&"-"&(UPPER(RIGHT(B2:B;8)))))}
```

I am trying to replace the function with a script but my code not works.

What is wrong?

```
function concatenate() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      var lr = sheet.getLastRow()
      var values1 = sheet.getSheetValues(2, 3, lr, 1);
      var values2 = sheet.getSheetValues(2, 4, lr, 1);
      var values3 = sheet.getSheetValues(2, 5, lr, 1);
      var values4 = sheet.getSheetValues(2, 2, lr, 1);
      var results = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < lr; i++) {
        results.push([values1[i][0].slice(0,1) + "-" + values2[i][0].slice(0,1) + values3[i][0].slice(0,1) + "-" + values4[i][0].slice(-8)]);
      }
      sheet.getRange(2, 1, results.length).setValues(results);
    }
```

P.S.

How can I also run the script every time there is an edit on a row?

Comment: What is the output supposed to be when it's working.  What does not working mean. And if you want to have it run where cells are edited manually by a user go read about triggers in the documentation.

Comment: I have this error: "TypeError: values4[i][0].slice is not a function (riga 11, file "Codice")"

Comment: What is values4[i][0]?  If it's not a string or an array then slice is not a method.  Try using the debugger to learn more about what is going on.

Comment: I would to concatenate the first character of the col C, the first character of the col D, the first character of the col E and the last eight characters of col B (values4[i][0]).

Comment: BTW this line `var values1 = sheet.getSheetValues(2, 3, lr, 1);` should be `var values1 = sheet.getSheetValues(2, 3, lr-1, 1);` as well as all of the other lines just like it.  Currently, your looping off of the end of your data.  That third parameter is number of lines not last line.

Comment: And so what string I could to replace?

Comment: I don't know show me data.  What are trying to accomplish? Also don't bother giving me a link to your spreadsheet because I won't click on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are sure that this isn't what you want?

```
function concatenate() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var results = [];
  for (var i=1;i<data.length; i++) {//if you have a header row start from one
    results.push([data[i][2].slice(0,1) + "-" + data[i][3].slice(0,1) + data[i][4].slice(0,1) + "-" + data[i][1].slice(-8)]);
  }
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, results.length,1).setValues(results);
}
```